# Row merge on Unix

Tags: bash, unix, merge, row

I have a file where data is like,

```
Line 1 01~Address~PIN~

Line 2 01~Line~Code~
```

The output should be

```
Line 1 01~AddressLine~PINCode~
```

How can I get this output using bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="~"} NR%2{f1=$1;f2=$2;f3=$3;next} {print f1,f2$2,f3$3}' file
```

(Or)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="~"} NR%2{prev=$0;next} {split(prev,arr,"~");print arr[1],arr[2]$2,arr[3]$3}' file
```